# React notify after a certain time when button is not clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout

I want to print an alert to the console if it doesn't click a button within a certain period of time, but if it clicks it doesn't show this alert

I tried using settimeout like this but it gives a warning after clicking

It's actually a very simple method that I tried.

```
  const [clicked , setClicked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    setTimeout(()=>{
      if (!clicked) {
        console.log(`alert`);
      }
    },[3000])
  
  }, [])

 return <button onClick={()=>setClicked(true)} className="ErrorEntrySideBttn">try me</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As-is, you should have `clicked` in your effect hook and then you can cancel the timeout in the effect hook's cleanup function:

```
  const [clicked , setClicked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout;
    if (!clicked) {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`alert`);
      }, 3000)
    }
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }, [clicked]);

 return <button onClick={()=>setClicked(true)} className="ErrorEntrySideBttn">try me</button>
```

Another approach would be to use a ref to track a boolean *assuming* you never want to have anything else dependent on this ref:

```
  const clicked = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      if (!clicked.current) {
        console.log(`alert`);
      }
    }, 3000)

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
    }
  }, []);

 return <button onClick={() => { clicked.current = true }} className="ErrorEntrySideBttn">try me</button>
```

Comment: appreciate you for your help, have a good day =]